# Setting Compass destination folder when source folder has subfolders

Tags: css, sass, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-compass

I am using Compass through grunt to compile a SASS file. My directory structure looks like this:

```
project/
    Gruntfile.js
    package.json
    sass/
        part1/
            part1.sass
    css/
```

And my Gruntfile.js:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    compass: {
        std: {
            options: {
                sassDir: 'sass',
                cssDir: 'css',
                specify: 'sass/part1/part1.sass',
                raw: 'disable_warnings = true\n'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

When I run my gruntfile, Compass outputs to `project/css/part1/part1.css`, but I want it to output to `project/css/part1.css` instead. How can I do this? Right now I am using an on_stylesheet_saved hook to move the file, but it is not very elegant.

Hopefully the question is clear, and thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't really know what's causing the error without a `Gruntfile.js`, but a behavior like this can only be caused by wrong configuration. Post it here and I'll have a look at it. :) (the -1 wasn't mine, btw)...

Comment: @WallaceSidhrée I edited the question to be clearer and included a specific minimum example. Any help you could offer would be much appreciated!

Comment: Just made the question's title more relevant to the problem you're trying to solve ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recreated your environment. I could simplify the `Gruntfile.js` even more:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    // Main project configuration
    grunt.initConfig({
        // Read NPM package information
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        // Compass
        compass: {
            std: {
                options: {
                    cssDir: 'css',
                    sassDir: 'sass'
                }
            }
        }
    });

    // Load the grunt tasks
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass');

    // Compile production files
    grunt.registerTask('std', [
        'compass:std'
    ]);

    // Default task(s)
    grunt.registerTask('default', 'std');

};
```

*What you are getting is the expected compass behavior.*

Reading a bit through the [grunt-contrib-compass](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass)'s readme, I see:

> Compass operates on a folder level. Because of this you don't specify any src/dest, but instead define the `sassDir` and `cssDir` options.

That means that you cannot change the path to where your `CSS` gets compiled to, only determine the path of the root folder to which all compiled files are written to.

While it can be annoying, `compass` is simply assuming that keeping the compilation true to the directory structure is supposed to be something you would rather do - which is somewhat opinionated.

You could still do what you want, by:

1. Restructuring your files so that they are where `compass` would expect them to be to comply to your intention. Namely dropping the `part1` directory and placing `part1.sass` under the `sass` folder.
2. Compiling your `CSS` files to a temporary folder like `tmp`, using another task like `copy` ([grunt-contrib-copy](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy)) to copy all `CSS` files to the `css` folder and then use a task like `clean` ([grunt-contrib-clean](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-clean)) to empty the `tmp` file. You would load the tasks in that order, so they run in the right sequence.